# How do I stop Visual Studio Code from changing the color of alternating rows when I make an edit?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Everything looks normal when I open a file in Visual Studio Code:

[image: Everything looks normal]

But the moment I type any character (or even the space bar) all alternating rows turn white, making it impossible to see the text:
[image: Alternating rows are colored in]

When I click out of the file and back into it, the alternating row colors are gone:
[image: Looks normal again]

But they reappear again as soon as anything is typed. This happens with any file that has more than 1 line. (If I create a new file, I can type on the first line with no problem, but as soon as I press return, the second line is white.)

I restored the default settings by deleting everything except the {} in settings.json, but the problem persists.

Comment: Did you try to reload with all extensions disabled and see if the problem remains?

Comment: try it in VSC-insiders (no extensions), if gone than find the offending setting or extension

Comment: you have Global/User settings and you have Folder settings and Multi Root Workspace settings

Comment: That was it. There was an extension that was causing it. Thank you!